# Fixing Python Dependencies The Right Way

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I'm just getting my first Python environment setup. All have gone well and it seems to be GPU enabled and all that good stuff.

However, I have one issue and no idea how to fix. After getting the correct install command for torch it informed of this issue:

```
Installing collected packages: torch
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
torchvision 0.8.2 requires torch==1.7.1, but you have torch 1.8.0+cu111 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed torch-1.8.0+cu111
```

As far as I can tell torchvision 0.8.2 is the latest version.

The environment seems happy at the moment as all these commands return expected things:

```
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)
```

I've seen some people talking about "patching requirements files" or updating dependencies. But I'm not sure of the best way to tackle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lock the version of a package in a requirements file. This file has the appropriate values.

requirements.txt:

```
torch==1.7.1
torchvision==0.8.2
```

The packages are installed via `pip` like so:

```sh
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You may have other dependencies for this project. In that case, you can generate a requirements.txt file with `pip` as well:

```sh
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#managing-packages-with-pip) on managing dependencies with `pip`

Comment: Fantastic, how i missed that link is a mystery. Thanks again.